# Seaborn distplot error: TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an index

Tags: numpy, seaborn

I test the usage of seaborn with even the simpleast example as follows:

```
sns.distplot(np.array([1,2,3], dtype="int64"))
```

but there still occurs the error:

**TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an index**

[The detailed error infomation is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrAez.png)

The version of python is 2.7.12 and the version of numpy is 1.12.1
Anyone encountered the same problem? You kind help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What version of seaborn?

Comment: This works for me on 0.7.1

Comment: My version is also 0.7.1...

Comment: Can you post the full traceback by editing the question? It would seem that the error is not from that line of code...

Comment: Looks like it's having problems deducing the number of bins.

Comment: Working for me in Seaborn 0.8.0